# Angular2: Component class and underlying class

Tags: javascript, angular

I often have the case that I want a component which renders to a DOM element and which needs some data for that. This data comes from objects I store in the parent component like that:

```js
@Component({
    template: '<child *ngFor="let child of children" [child]="child"/>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    children: Array<Child>;

    constructor () {
        this.children = [
            new Child('Foo'),
            new Child('Bar'),
        ]
    }
}

class Child {
    name: string;

    constructor (name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: 'My name is {{child.name}}'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input child: Child;
}
```

Here, Child and ChildComponent represent the same entity. But despite that I have to use two classes and two instances for each entity instance and I have to pass one object to the 'wrapping' component class. That seems unnecessarily complicated to me.

I would find it much easier if I could somehow 'merge' the classes `Child` and `ChildComponent` like that (imaginary syntax):

```js
@Component({
    template: '<child *ngFor="let this of children"/>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
    children: Array<MergedChildComponent>;

    constructor () {
        this.children = [
            new MergedChildComponent('Foo'),
            new MergedChildComponent('Bar'),
        ]
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: 'My name is {{name}}'
})
export class MergedChildComponent {
    name: string;

    constructor (name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why not just pass `'Foo'` and `'Bar'` to the `ChildComponent`?

Comment: This was just a simple example. In reality the `Child` class has a whole lot more fields. Or imagine the `Child` class has nested Objects as fields. Do you think it would be a good idea to serialize them to a JSON string and then pass it again to the `ChildComponent` which in return needs to deserialize it again?

Comment: You can pass objects if you use `[inputName]="objValue"` instead of `inputName="{{objValue}}"`

Comment: Alright, but the problem with too many fields remains. In my view `Child` and `ChildComponent` are one and the same, just different "representations", hence I don't want to pass data between them.

Comment: To me it doesn't make sense. The component is to render the view and update the model, and the model holds the data, and it's usually a great idea to not merge these component and model.

Comment: OK, that partly answers my question. In the example above it would lead to cleaner and more understandable code. You'd save one class and get a better performance. But if it's not the Angular2 way of doing it I accept that.

Comment: Nope, definitely the Angular2 way. Components need to be created by DI, therefore unlikely there is a way to accomplish what you want anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to what I was trying to do (imaginary code at the bottom). And that doesn't seem to be the Angular2 way of doing it. Thank you anyway.